# How to view CD key for a Steam game?

Tags: steam

I have purchased a game on Steam and can not find out the details of the file or purchase.
How does one find their CD Key from a game purchased in Steam?

Comment: I love how Steam gives you the CD key right when you launch the game for the first time, which is never when you actually need it. Then, when you **do** need it, it's hard to find.

Answer (score 17):

In late 2019, Steam got an updated library which changed where CD Keys are in the library screen; there's no longer a "CD Key" option in the game's library page.  Instead, on the library screen:

1. In the game list on the left, right-click the game name
2. Click Manage
3. Click CD keys

[image: Steam CD Keys menu]

Comment: Note that when a game has multiple entries in your Library, one might have the CD key whereas the other may not. For me, it was only on the Single Player entry...

Answer (score 13):

Most Steam games don't *have* any CD keys. Everything is attached to your account and can be downloaded and run inside the client, and most games require no extra verification - the Steam client itself is sufficient.

For the games that *do* have CD keys, right-click the game in your library and click View CD key.

[image: Right-click menu for Neverwinter Nights 2]

This will show a dialog with your CD keys for the product (actual keys redacted here):

[image: CD key dialog]

Steam will also show a reminder on the Steam Overlay when you launch the game, allowing you to access the keys from within the game. Here, you can also tell Steam to not show this reminder again (in case you already entered the key inside the game, or if the game doesn't actually use the key).

Answer (score 5):

If a game requires a CD key, you can right-click the game in your games list and select "View CD key".

[image: Screenshot of context menu with "View CD key" option]

Not all games have this option. If, for some reason, you need the CD key of a game which does not have this option, I suggest contacting Steam Support about the issue.

Answer (score 4):

**UPD**: as steam updated their library interface again, my answer is no longer valid. Please refer to [Powerlord's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/360754/202341) for the updated info.

========================================

In the eve of 2019 I couldn't find this setting in the context menus for some reason, but can see it currently present under **Links** category of a game:

[image]

Comment: Those links can't be seen after Steam has updated the library's view.
Is there a way to find them now?

Comment: @Hirokuro the Powerlord's answer seems to be true for the nowadays library, however I found that some keys have just disappeared..