# Finding activation key

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I know this question has been posed before but I can't find a current solution that seems to work. I'm trying to find my activation key for some games, and I've tried all the previous solutions to this problem that I've found here.

What I've tried:

1. Right-clicking the game in the library menu to click on "View CD-key" (there was no such button).
2. Clicking the cog-wheel on the game in question and looking under "Manage" (no button for keys)
3. Checking under "Links" in the game menu, except I can't even find a links category

Anyone who knows how this works now? I'm at a loss. The games I want to find the key for is Skyrim and Lego The Hobbit

Comment: You need to be specific on what games you're having issues with. Different games have various methods of key activations and it is difficult for us to assume what specific issues you are having.

Comment: Ok I didn't know that! I've edited the original post for the games I want to know about

Comment: @senpai I really don't think that's the case. I think some games have activation codes simply because they were provided by third parties, and activated that way in Steam, and even in that case these are not always retraceable. The only way to view product codes is through the method provided in the answers of →

Comment: ..this possible duplicate: [How to view CD key for a Steam game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158433/how-to-view-cd-key-for-a-steam-game)

Comment: I've tried all these solutions, none of which work sadly. My steam doesn't even look the same? :/

Comment: What is your end goal? What are you trying to do with the CD keys?

Answer (score 0):

Skyrim is a Steam required game. The "KEY" is not to activate the game, but to get a Steam digital copy of the game. Once you get this code, you can literally throw away the box and disc, go to Steam, and then just add the game via the "Activate a Product on Steam".

If the game is already installed, there is no way to "retrieve" the CD Key. You cannot give your copy of Skyrim to someone else, hence the lack of option to see said key.

The likelihood of this also applying to Lego The Hobbit is high. The "View CD Key" option was for much older games that authenticate through their own system (like Games for Windows Live, GameSpy, and so forth). Most games nowadays simply go with Steam's own authentication and once you activate a product, you can't "take it off your account and give it away."